# not able to make ninject work in asp.net mvc4 web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I am learning how to use Ninject in my asp.net MVC 4 web application. I am not sure I have got the concepts right. This is what I did.

1) Installed Ninject.MVC3 using Manage NuGet

2) Added the following code in NinjectWebCommon.cs(this file was added automatically by Nuget in App_start folder)

```
  private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        **kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>.To<ProductRepository>;**
    }
```

3) Controller Code

```
Public Class ProductController
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Private _rProduct As IProductRepository
'
' GET: /Product

Sub ProductController(ProductRepository As IProductRepository)
    _rProduct = ProductRepository
End Sub


Function ProductList() As ActionResult
    Return View(_rProduct.GetProducts())
End Function
End Class
```

4) IProductRepository code

```
Public Interface IProductRepository
Function GetProducts() As IQueryable(Of Product)
End Interface
```

5) ProductRepository code

```
Public Class ProductRepository
Implements IProductRepository

Public Function GetProducts() As IQueryable(Of Product) Implements   IProductRepository.GetProducts
    Return (New List(Of Product)() From {
      New Product() With {.Name = "Football", .Price = 25},
        New Product() With {.Name = "Surf board", .Price = 179},
        New Product() With {.Name = "Running shoes", .Price = 95}
    }.AsQueryable())
End Function
End Class
```

When I debug, the control does not go to the breakpoint in 
RegistryServices() in NinjectWebCommon.cs instead comes to the ProductList() in the ProductController. At this point _rProduct is Nothing. Can you please explain me what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this page https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application you have some extra steps to perform because you are using VB.Net.

> NOTE: If you're using VB.NET to develop an MVC3 application then there are few additional steps to make everything work as expected:
>
> - In App_Start: rename NinjectMVC3.cs to NinjectMVC3.vb
> - Replace contents of NinjectMVC3.vb with contents provided in this gist: https://gist.github.com/923618

**Edit:** Here's a NinjectWebCommon.vb that I got working. Make note of the Namespace (I'm using "VbMvc" for my project name). I did not modify Global.asax.vb and breakpoints are hit in RegisterServices.

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper
Imports Ninject.Web.Common
Imports Ninject.Web
Imports Ninject
Imports Ninject.Web.Mvc

<Assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(GetType(VbMvc.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "StartNinject")> 
<Assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(GetType(VbMvc.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "StopNinject")> 

Namespace VbMvc.App_Start
    Public Module NinjectWebCommon
        Private ReadOnly bootstrapper As New Bootstrapper()

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Starts the application
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub StartNinject()
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(GetType(NinjectHttpModule))
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(GetType(OnePerRequestHttpModule))
            bootstrapper.Initialize(AddressOf CreateKernel)
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Stops the application.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub StopNinject()
            bootstrapper.ShutDown()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        Private Function CreateKernel() As IKernel
            Dim kernel = New StandardKernel()

            kernel.Bind(Of Func(Of IKernel))().ToMethod(Function(ctx) Function() New Bootstrapper().Kernel)
            kernel.Bind(Of IHttpModule)().To(Of HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule)()

            RegisterServices(kernel)
            Return kernel

        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Load your modules or register your services here!
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        Private Sub RegisterServices(ByVal kernel As IKernel)
            ''kernel.Load(New Bindings.ServiceBindings(), New Bindings.RepositoryBindings(), New Bindings.PresentationBindings(), New Bindings.CrossCuttingBindings())
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: I did the changes you had mentioned, but getting the same result. On debug, it hits the break point in the controller->ProductList() and _rProducts is still nothing !

Comment: Did you remember to restore your `RegisterServices` additions?

Comment: I did :) Private Sub RegisterServices(ByVal kernel As IKernel)
            kernel.Bind(Of IProductRepository).To(Of ProductRepository)()
        End Sub

Comment: Also, did you see the comments in the gist regarding version differences? Someone posted modified code for the gist.

Comment: I did that too. I'm really wondering why it is not hitting my breakpoint in the RegisterServices method!

Comment: What's your Global.asax.vb look like?

Comment: I have not modified my global.asax since I installed Ninject.MVC3 which I thought will do the integration. This is my global.asax.vb                                Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: @user2721870 see edits. I think some code got omitted by the filter on that gist page.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in your `Global.asax` that `RegisterServices()` is invoked by the `Application_Start()` method that is invoked **once** upon application start (or recycle) and **not** for every http request.

If you want to debug your `Application_Start()` follow the instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2007/12/13/workaround-debugging-global-aspx-cs-application-start-with-asp-net-web-server-within-visual-studio.aspx).