# How do you bootstrap an asp.net application with Ninject for VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ninject

I've used Nuget to pull in Ninject and the .Web and .Web.Common extensions. It's my understanding that I shouldn't need to touch the global.asax file and only need to register my modules in NinjectWebCommon, but this file is pulled in from NuGet as a C# file, and simply converting it causes errors.

Does anyone have a working NinjectWebCommon.vb file they can share?

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19525229/116923) of any help?

Comment: I was hoping it would! Unfortunately, the converted VB code that's shown in the answer fails on the second operation in the CreateKernel() method. "Overload resolution failed because no Public 'ToMethod' can be called with these arguments"

Comment: Try converting the C# to VB.Net using a [converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue - a legacy VB.NET web application hosting Web API 2 -

> "Overload resolution failed because no Public 'ToMethod' can be called
>   with these arguments"

I've managed to get around this by moving the creation of the Bootstrapper and setting the reference to the Kernel property from being inline, to being performed before the binding:

```
Dim k = New Bootstrapper().Kernel
kernel.Bind(Of Func(Of IKernel))().ToMethod(Function(ctx) Function() k)
kernel.Bind(Of IHttpModule)().To(Of HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule)()
```

Hope this helps,
Scott